# Can i improve it?

Tags: sql

i have implemented a query search for all entries with the year 2014 by following code. Can we consider this design of index and select optimal for given query from performance perspective?

```
CREATE INDEX item_idx ON item (created);

SELECT text, created
FROM item
WHERE YEAR(created) = '2014’;
```

is it an optimal solution or there can be an improvement possible ?

Comment: If your code is entirely functional, but could use improvement, please post it On Code Review instead.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, an index is not going to work on a function like `YEAR()`.  The following will generally use an index:

```
SELECT text, created
FROM item
WHERE created >= '2014-01-01' AND created < '2015-01-01';
```

Note that a better index is on `(created, text)`.  This is a covering index for the query.

Also, the format of date constants can vary among databases.